# How to draw a segment of the iris shutter using QuartzCore

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, core-image

Anyone knows how to draw a one segment of an iris that would look at least similar to the original apple camera shutter?

http://stickertagapp.com/_files/_iris.png

I am trying to replicate this functionality:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:0.3];
animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
[animation setType:@"cameraIris"];
[cameraView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Comment: I think this is not possible with Quartz core, but possible with Core Animation, According to your pic, there are 8 blades init (Octagonal). SO, draw those 8 blades and then animate them using Core Animation.

Comment: Yeah, I will be animating those with CA ... the problem is that I don't know how to do the blade :( ... I kinda can draw the lines of it but have no idea how to do the filling (gradient and the shadow)