# change color of shutter animation iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, caanimation

I am making a photography based application i have used a shutter animation for progress.

here is my code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(makeRound) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
-(void)makeRound
{
    [[[self.view viewWithTag:90] layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [[[self.view viewWithTag:90] layer] setCornerRadius:75.0];
    [[[self.view viewWithTag:90] layer] setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [[[self.view viewWithTag:90] layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [(UILabel *)[[self.view viewWithTag:90] viewWithTag:991] setText:@"Loading.."];
    [self shutter];
}
-(void)shutter
{
    CATransition *shutterAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [shutterAnimation setDelegate:self];
    [shutterAnimation setDuration:1.5];
    [shutterAnimation setType:@"cameraIris"];
    [shutterAnimation setValue:@"cameraIris" forKey:@"cameraIris"];
    [shutterAnimation setRepeatCount:1];
    [[[self.view viewWithTag:90] layer] addAnimation:shutterAnimation forKey:@"cameraIris"];
}
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(shutter) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

and my output is like this.

[image]

but i want to change this black color of shutter.Please share your knowledge and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the camera iris exposes a "`color`" property, I'm pretty certain you won't be able to change the color of the iris blades to anything arbitrarily.  That artwork is built into the OS and is static.

If you are set on changing the color of the iris blades, you may need to do your own animation with your own graphics ([which other people have had to do, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470114/how-to-draw-a-segment-of-the-iris-shutter-using-quartzcore)).